# Assign color to polydata in paraview

Tags: paraview

I have a polydata dataset to which I would like to assign a (single) color (ideally rgb vector). Is there a way to achieve this simply without "breaking it" into cells?

Answer (score 0):

```
# vtk DataFile Version 5.1
```

vtk output
ASCII
DATASET POLYDATA
POINTS 16 float
0.500000 0.100000 -0.000000
0.353553 0.100000 -0.353553
0.000000 0.100000 -0.500000
-0.353553 0.100000 -0.353553
-0.500000 0.100000 -0.000000
-0.353553 0.100000 0.353553
0.000000 0.100000 0.500000
0.353553 0.100000 0.353553
0.500000 -0.100000 -0.000000
0.353553 -0.100000 -0.353553
0.000000 -0.100000 -0.500000
-0.353553 -0.100000 -0.353553
-0.500000 -0.100000 -0.000000
-0.353553 -0.100000 0.353553
0.000000 -0.100000 0.500000
0.353553 -0.100000 0.353553
POLYGONS 11 48
OFFSETS vtktypeint64
0 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 48
CONNECTIVITY vtktypeint64
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
0 8 15 7
1 9 8 0
2 10 9 1
3 11 10 2
4 12 11 3
5 13 12 4
6 14 13 5
7 15 14 6
8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
CELL_DATA 10
SCALARS SMEARED float 1
LOOKUP_TABLE victor
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
LOOKUP_TABLE victor 1
1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000

Comment: you should format such text by using three backquotes (``` ` ```) before the block  and three after

Answer (score 0):

To set a uniform color on a polydata in ParaView, you should use the [Display Properties Panel](https://docs.paraview.org/en/latest/UsersGuide/displayingData.html#id2). There is an `Edit` button under the `Solid Color` dropdown list.

Comment: Yes, but I need to have color pre-defined in my original VTK file.that is Matlab generated based on the output of a finite element program Each set will have to have a different color